# How do you add separate files for both iOS and Android?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to use Material widgets for Android and Cupertino widgets for IOS. How do I add separate files for both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import `dart:io` then use `Platform().isIOS` to determine whether it's Android or iOS and then call a widget in a custom file.

The custom file needs to be imported with something like `import 'androidFile.dart';` and can then be accessed via it's widgets/class name.